# How do you find and replace a line in a text document through terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have a shell script that was created with vim.  The only think i know about it is a var name.

Somewhere in the document there is a line:

```
SecondHome='/Users/me/Documents/code/'
```

The value of this is incorrect, but through shellscripts carrying out new functionality without changing what that shell script does.

I was thinking to do something like:

```
grep -n "SecondHome" somefile.sh
```

which will spit out line numbers + the matchs, but only change the first one, as that is the variable definition.

I was thinking to then do a replace on that line somehow to make it look like:

```
export SecondHome=$DirPath/code/$Repo
```

then run the script file which has been modified.

```
#!/bin/zsh
export DirPath=/Users/me/Documents/
export Repo=MyNewRepo/
export LineNumber=$(grep -n "SecondHome" somefile.sh)
#carry out replace on somefile.sh at $LineNumber with: export SecondHome=$DirPath/code/$Repo/
. ./somefile.sh
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i.bak '/SecondHome=/s,=.*,=$DirPath/code/$Repo,' somefile.sh
```

`sed -i.bak expression file` performs the `expression` on the file, modifying it `-i`n place.

The expression is on the form `/regex/command`, which runs `command` on lines that match `regex`.

The `command` is `s,search,replace,`, which searches and replaces text.

In other words, it modifies files by finding lines containing `SecondHome=`, and replacing everything after the equals sign with your string.

You can also replace the single quotes with double quotes if your $DirPath/$Repo is defined in  the replacement script and not in somefile.sh

Comment: For the purposes of documentation, could you describe what this does for future people looking at this post?   I dont understand all the params.